# How to pull a property like "customer.gender" from an array of object with map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using javascript map to loop through an array of object. Today i have to loop through an array of object which looks like,

```
averageReport = [
    {
      "result": 150.54909908933223,
      "customer.gender": "Female"
    },
    {
      "result": 150.35230422844595,
      "customer.gender": "Male"
    }
  ];
```

What i tried to get only the "customer.gender",

```
averageReport
      .map(x => console.log(x.customer.gender)
```

)

I get the error "Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined"
[code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9tsnfv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
averageReport
      .map(x => console.log(x["customer.gender"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you named your key `customer.gender` you can't use dot-notation to get the value, you have to use bracket notation (`[]`).

Also mapping to `console.log()` doesn't make much sense (since `console.log()` returns `undefined`, you are creating a new array of `undefined` when using `map()` here), just use `forEach()`:

```js
averageReport = [{
    "result": 150.54909908933223,
    "customer.gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "result": 150.35230422844595,
    "customer.gender": "Male"
  }
];

averageReport.forEach(x => console.log(x["customer.gender"]));
```

If you want to access the property using dot-notation, you have to make `customer` an object and `gender` a property of it, like so:

```
averageReport = [{
    "result": 150.54909908933223,
    "customer": {
      "gender": "Female"
    }
  },
  {
    "result": 150.35230422844595,
    "customer": {
      "gender": "Male"
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: why map doesnt make sense?

Comment: @anonymous: Because `.map` returns a new array with the return values of the callback. You are supposed to use the new array. If you don't care about it, `forEach` is the more appropriate solution.

Comment: I added an explanation, not only does it return a new array, it returns a new array looking like this: `[undefined, undefined]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for accessing the `customer.gender` property. Try the following :

```js
var averageReport = [ { "result": 150.54909908933223, "customer.gender": "Female" }, { "result": 150.35230422844595, "customer.gender": "Male" } ];
  
var result = averageReport.map(x =>x["customer.gender"]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: How is your answer different from others. Looks like same.

Comment: @anonymous they posted their answer at about the same time the others were posted, all answers were posted within a minute of each other, the answer looks so similar because this is the only real answer to the problem

Comment: The time of post is visible.